# How do I display latitude longitude data on a UTM map?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I'm relatively new to GIS, so I may use incorrect terms, but I'll try my best.  I'm using ArcView 10.  My current coordinate system information is as follows.

[image: Data Frame Properties]

I believe this is correct, as it is the default coordinate system in our environment.

I have a CSV file that includes information I'd like to display on a map alongside all the other GIS layers I have available.  The problem I'm having is that the information in the CSV file is in latitude and longitude.

I was able to "Add Data" to import the CSV file.  The problem I'm having is displaying the data visually.  Using the "Display XY Data" tool, I have the following settings.

[image: Display XY Data]

When I click "OK", the data is plotted visually, but not where it should be.  I think it's treating the relatively small latitude and longitude values as whatever projection the map is using.  I can see the layer is displayed if I zoom out to 1:30,000,000, so I am successfully displaying the data, however it should be shown on top of the existing layers.

Is there a way to convert the latitude and longitude data from a CSV file on import to display correctly?

**Update:**  Here's a sample ofthe CSV data I'm working with.

```
WorkOrder  Lat           Lng
00001      46.51169347  -84.32934394
00002      46.51232708  -84.33508238
00003      46.50809868  -84.32696865
00004      46.50980299  -84.33103097
00005      46.51359957  -84.33543261
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the coordinates from your CSV file? I suspect that your data is not in UTM. First guess would be it's in the WGS84 datum (try using this when importing). In order to use the data in UTM you will need to project it.

Comment: @Radar I added a sample of the CSV file I'm working with.

Comment: the coordinate system input for the add xy data is where you enter the coordinate system of your data, not how you want it to output. the way you have entered the utm system is telling arcmap to read the coordinates AS UTM. the coordinate system input should match your lat/long input, as explained by radouxju below. once you import the data, you can use the 'Project' tool to convert it to UTM 16N

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you look at the bottom of your second picture, there is a small "edit" button. Press it and you will be able to change the coordinate system. If you don't know about the correct coordinate system, try first with WGS84 which is now the most commonly used geographic coordinate system. Furthermore, you should then go to the properties of your dataframe > coordinate system in order to set the transformation between WGS 84 and your datum. This is necessary because ArcGIS reprojects the data on the fly but does not choose the datum conversion if you don't tell him.

Comment: The map coordinate system was "NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_16N", so I tried out one close in name, "NAD_1983".  Worked perfectly.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @dangowans That actually won't be perfect, but it's close. You need to click Edit and choose the coordinate system your data is in. In this case, yours is almost certainly in Lat/Long, WGS84 as radouxju says. In ArcGIS, it's listed as "WGS 1984". Choose that.

Comment: @DanC Thanks for the tip.  WGS 1984 gives me positive results as well.